# android studio how to specify a specific box in sql for each edittext

Tags: android

I have create the table with 2 column

I want to store the text of the edit text1 in the (first column first row) with updating data

,And  store the text of the edit text2 in the (first column second row) with updating data

can some one show me how with example

Answer (score 0):

When you put in databse a new value for your table automatically the database create a new row.. for example :

```
TextView your_text_1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_text_1);
TextView your_text_2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_text_2);
Button your_botton= (Button )findViewById(R.id.your_botton);
```

Now when you click on the button insert the 2 row

```
textValue= new String[2];
textValue[0]=your_text_1.getText().toString();
textValue[1]=your_text_2.getText().toString();
for (int i=0;i<textValue.lenght;i++){
ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
    v.put(ColumnName, textValue[i]);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, v);}
```